# CFERROR causing browser to display Coldfusion source code

Tags: exception, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When there is an exception error Coldfusion will throw in the error.  I handle it with

```
<cferror
    template = "exception.cfm"
    type = "exception"
    mailTo = "webmaster@mydomain.com">
```

This works fine for "exception" errors.  There is also the validation errors.  But since I want to catch both I put type="request" which supposedly catches both:

```
<cferror
    template = "exception.cfm"
    type = "request"
    mailTo = "webmaster@mydomain.com">
```

The problem is when I put type="request" and an exception occurs, the exception.cfm is being displayed with all the Coldfusion source code showing in the browser's source code viewing!  It works fine if I put type="exception".  This is very weird and I don't expect CF code to show in browser no matte what, but it does.  Is this some CF Admin settings issue or a CF9 bug?

Comment: You've got your answer, but another question for you: if you're using CF9, why are you still using `<cferror>`, instead of Application.cfc's `onError()`?

Comment: If only someone can show me how.  I am very new to Application.cfc  I am starting to read on it.  How would I code onError with my above template?

Comment: 1) Try to implement something; 2) if/when you have issues, document what you've done, what the problems were, and what investigative steps you took. Then raise a question here with all that info ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use CFML tags when the error type is **Request**. That is why your ColdFusion source code is being displayed in the browser. But when the error type is **Exception**, you can use CFML tags, functions. Check out the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0bb9b-7ffc.html) for more information.

With type **Request**, you can use nine CFML `Error` variables, such as `Error.Diagnostics`, by enclosing them with number # signs. To know more, see [cferror documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d29.html)

I hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I would have never found out this reading the CFERROR doc.  It is just weird that why Request has to be treated any different.  I have that error.diagnostics on my exception page... only if Request had work.  The error handling of CF is totally weird I have to say.

Comment: *I would have never found out this reading the CFERROR doc* Sure you would, but sometimes you have to read the docs closely - and more than once. I remember missing it the first time around too ;) We have all made that mistake.

Comment: @Leigh When a visitor encounter a **Request** error on site, how am I ever going to be notified without CFMAIL working?  Is there a way I can log it somewhere if I can't send myself an mail?

Comment: The year is 2021 and this answer just bailed me out. It's super buried in the docs!! https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cferror.html